# androidでチャットアプリ

Tags: android, firebase

androidでチャットアプリを作りたいと考えています。
しかしながら、基本構成がわかりません。
Firebaseを使えばよさそうです。

realtime databaseと
Firebase Cloud Messaging Android 
の２つでしょうか？

realtime databaseを使えば、２つのアンドロイド端末間で、同じチャット画面が表示されると思います。しかしながら、片方の端末を使っている人がactivityを閉じてしまった場合、その片方の人は、activityが更新されたかどうか、わからないので、Firebase Cloud Messaging Android で、チャットが着ましたと通知する必要があると思うんです。

２人でチャットしていて、片方の人が画面を閉じてしまった場合、相手に、簡単なメッセージを飛ばして、通知する方法を実現するやり方を知りたいです。当然、画面を閉じないでちゃんと表示された場合は、簡単なメッセージは通知しません。

realtime database
Firebase Cloud Messaging Android

どっちも、ちょっとだけ違うような気がします。

Answer (score 1):

どのあたりが違うような気がしているのでしょうか？
Realtime Databaseでチャットのメイン部分を作り，通知はFirebase Cloud Messagingで送れば良いのではないでしょうか．

Answer (score 0):

参考になるか分かりませんが、
私も同じようなアプリを作っています。
チャットアプリならYoutubeで、
「Chat app」と検索すると色々出てきますよ。
私が参考にしてるYoutube載せておきます。
https://youtu.be/8Pv96bvBJL4